# Web API Post get related data from json.stringify

Tags: .net, json, vb.net, web, model-binding

I have an html page with a button on it. Here are the functions that are important:

```
function updateClick() {
    SOP10100 = new Object();
    SOP10100.CUSTNMBR = "5000";
    SOP10100.SHIPMTHD = "FedEX";
    SOP10100.SOP10200 = [{ itemnmbr: "120604", quantity: 3, unitprice: .98, uofm: "ROLL" }, { itemnmbr: "120604", quantity: 1, unitprice: 4.98, uofm: "6 ROLL" }, { itemnmbr: "120604", quantity: 2, unitprice: 10.98, uofm: "12 ROLL" }]

    salesOrderCreate(SOP10100);
}

function salesOrderCreate(sOP10100) {
   $.ajax({
        url: '/api/SOP10100',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify(sOP10100),
        success: function (data) {
            salesOrderSuccess(data);
        },
        error: function (request, message, error) {
            handleException(request, message, error);
        }
    });
}
```

Here is the controller that handles the click:

```
' POST: api/SOP10100
<ResponseType(GetType(SOP10100))>
Function PostSOP10100(ByVal sOP10100 As SOP10100) As IHttpActionResult
    If Not ModelState.IsValid Then
        Return BadRequest(ModelState)
    End If

    Try
```

'create the document header
            Dim otaSOPHdrIvcInsert As New Serialization.taSopHdrIvcInsert

```
        'populate the header
        With otaSOPHdrIvcInsert
            .DOCID = "EQ SALE ORD"
            .BACHNUMB = "webOrder"
            .LOCNCODE = "WAREHOUSE"
            .DOCDATE = DateString 'Today
            .CUSTNMBR = sOP10100.CUSTNMBR
            .SHIPMTHD = sOP10100.SHIPMTHD
            .REFRENCE = sOP10100.REFRENCE
    End With
```

Here is where I'm stuck. I need to loop through the SOP10200 (which are the order lines) and for each one do something like this:

```
Dim otaSOPLineIvcInsert As New Serialization.taSopLineIvcInsert_ItemsTaSopLineIvcInsert

With otaSOPLineIvcInsert
    .SOPNUMBE = strSopNumber
    .SOPTYPE = 2
    .DOCDATE = DateString
    .ITEMNMBR = sOP10100.SOP10200.itemnmbr
End With
```

But I can't seem to be able to get to the `itemnmbr` in code. I can see it when debugging, so I know it is there.

If this wasn't coming from an API but a linq query I would do a query and then

```
For Each IV00101 In query
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. I know the code is in VB, but the problem also applies to C#.

Comment: For Each IV00101 In sOP10100.SOP10200 ?

Comment: OMG that worked. I would have swore I tried it but I guess not. Thank you.

Comment: No problem.  I've added an answer so the question can be completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to access the collection property SOP10200 to get access to it's items:

```
 For Each IV00101 IN sOP10100.SOP10200

      'Do Work

 Next
```